# why is my google apps script taking long to execute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use this apps script code to duplicate my sheet with permissions as google sheet doesnt duplicate sheets with permissions. Before now it takes less than 2 mins to execute the script but now it exceeds the max execution time and the duplicated sheet ends up no retaining the permissions.

please find the apps script code below

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var sheetNames = ["9 June", "10 June", "11 June"]; // Please set copied sheet names here.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

  // Copy template sheet.
  var copiedSheetIds = sheetNames.map(function(e) {return sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(e).getSheetId()});

  // Retrieve protected ranges from Template sheet.
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId).sheets;
  var templateSheet = sheets.filter(function(e) {return e.properties.title == "Template"});
  var protectedRanges = templateSheet[0].protectedRanges;

  // Create request body.
  var resources = copiedSheetIds.map(function(e) {
    return protectedRanges.map(function(f) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(f));
      delete obj.protectedRangeId;
      if (obj.warningOnly) delete obj.editors;
      obj.range.sheetId = e;
      return {"addProtectedRange": {"protectedRange": obj}};
    });
  });
  resources = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], resources);

  // Set protected ranges to copied sheets
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests": resources}, spreadsheetId);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you running the script (Do you executing it from the script editor or from a trigger or from a UI element?) Have you tried to execute it using the debugger? If so, on what line does it gets stuck?